# Looking for an expression that sounds worse than "cardboard" to describe blandness of a food

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

How would you exaggeratedly express food that tastes nothing to sound even worse than "It tastes like cardboard"? I want a word that sounds beyond a average man can imagine. "Shit" would have its unique flavour, so I wouldn't put that in the list.

Comment: It tastes… bad!

Comment: Chalk, straw, sawdust, newspaper, fertilizer (leaving it up to ones imagination as to what kind), dry dog food, raw potato, bird poop, Styrofoam.

Comment: It tastes like cardboard that's had the flavor removed.

Comment: @HotLicks "bird poop" sounds intriguing, have you ever tasted it before?

Comment: Yeah, mr hot. It's indeed intriguing how you got to know how "bird poop" tastes like. Did you also dive into your dog's bag of chow, when you ran out of human food?

Comment: Hey, if it worked for Riggs...

Comment: @HotLicks: if you put “sawdust” or “Styrofoam” into an answer, I would vote for them over any of the current crop.  They should be very widely-understood (unlike *pabulum* or *stale matzoh*), not controversial (unlike *tofu*), and unlikely to be misunderstood as emphasising any other aspect (unlike *shoe leather* or *stone soup*).

Comment: "Kitty litter" is another one that came to mind.  You can use you imagination as to whether it's "fresh" or used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shoe leather (I'm thinking of Charlie Chaplin trying to eat his boot).

Stale matzoh.  (My mother described the most successful diet she ever went on like this: she stopped taking a lunch to work.  The only food in her office was a box of ancient matzoh.)

Stone soup.

Comment: Which one fit the bill?  I'm curious!

Answer (score 3):

Food that's particularly bland and tasteless is often described as *[pablum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pablum?s=t)* (or *Pablum*):

> a brand of soft, bland cereal for infants

It's amusing to note that when Pablum was [introduced in 1931](https://books.google.com/books?id=neeFJborlE4C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=tastes%20like%20pablum&source=bl&ots=QyBlyyB_hh&sig=Xy70OWc8CNo5Cd7qjWuNz11zlrE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WAoeVfPXL8ipogSf8IGQAg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=tastes%20like%20pablum&f=false),

> media reports at the time said the cereal tasted like "boiled Kleenex"
>   and "had the consistency of mucilage and smelled like the inside of an
>   old cardboard box."

Comment: I'd use "pablum" in a research paper but it sounds too mild for me to use it in a conversation (e.g. verbal fight). I think it's due to lack of 'f' or 't' consonants to remind you of insults like "f word" or "s word".

Comment: Or, something which is very similar to pablum, and often used as an expression for bland: "wallpaper paste".

Answer (score 0):

**Banal** is a rather harsh adjective you could use to describe tastelessness.

If you wish to really exaggerate you could say: *"The dish was mortally banal"*

Answer (score 0):

**shirt backing** I once had an omelet in England that tasted like shirt backing.
(same as cardboard but sounds cooler).